# Associate models with eachother Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, associations

I have this if statement, if no $address information has been added to a user, then create, else go on.

```
public function getIndexEditClient(Request $request, $id) {
    $regions = DB::table("regions")->pluck("name","id");
    $address = Address::where('id', $request->address_id)->with('region')->first();


    if(empty($address)){
      $address =  Address::create([
             'street_name',
             'house_number',
             'postcode',
             'city_id',
             'country_id',
             'region_id'
        ]);
            // assiociate address with user 

                //then save it

    }else{

    $data = $this->data->getEditClient($id);
    $admins = $this->data->getAdmin();
    return view('client.edit', [
        'client'        => $data, 
        'admins'        => $admins,
        'regions'       => $regions,
        'address'       => $address
        ]);
    }
}
```

The only thing is, i have to associate the user(client) with the addres @ the commented lines. I don't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$user->address()->associate($address);
$user->save();
```

Comment: I think the problem is within the array of create.